# How to place a header image above navigation in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, css

I am using theme Banshee on (http://adriangraphics.com/truturf/) and can't figure out how to put a header image (as seen on http://globalsynturf.com/) above the navigation. I want my logo, along with phone number, etc above the navigation on my WordPress site. I'm assuming I have to change the Header PHP, but unsure how.

Answer (score 0):

In your header.php find:

```
<div class="row">
```

Then inside of this find:

```
<div class="3">
    <div id="logo">
```

Take the contents of this entire div, and cut it.

Then above the `<div class="row">`, make the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div id="logo">
         //rest of the logo code
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```